# How do I distinguish between 2 Indy clients that connected from the same IP address?

Tags: delphi, sockets, client-server, indy

Sorry, [links](https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=poyJUpnKO8eN8Qe4-4C4Cg#q=indy+documentation) to Indy documentation are currently not working for me. I don't know if the sites are down or whatever but they're not loading in my browser at the moment.

I have a TIdCmdTcpServer in one "server" application, and a TIdCmdTcpClient in another "client" application. I know how to get the IP address of the Client once it has connected. What I don't know is how to distinguish between 2 clients that connect from the same ip address. Can anyone **help**?

Comment: www.indyproject.org is down at the moment, but http://indyproject.org/index.de.aspx works

Comment: www.indyproject.org works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really an Indy question, more a general networking one.

Different clients at the same address must use distinct ports. And here I mean the port at the client end of the connection. So you distinguish between different clients at the same address by dint of them using different ports.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT use `TIdCmdTCPClient` with `TIdCmdTCPServer`. They are not meant to be used together, and it is very easy to deadlock your communications with them, as they both use internal reading threads that expect the other peer to send data. Use `TIdTCPClient` with `TIdCmdTCPServer` or `TIdCmdTCPClient` with `TIdTCPServer`.

With that said, you could use the client's remote IP/Port to differentiate, but it is generally better to make your own identifier instead, such as requiring clients to log in with a username, that you can then track as needed.